# Partial Derivative Question involving arcsin

Tags: calculus

Suppose $u(x,y) = \sin (( x \sin^{-1} (y))$

Find ${\partial u \over \partial x}, {\partial u \over \partial y}, {\partial^2 u \over \partial x^2}, {\partial^2 u \over \partial y^2}$ and ${\partial^2 u \over \partial x \partial y}$

I think you have to use chain rule. I'm a bit confused as the solution given doesn't explain the process, it just gives the answers which isn't good for revision and understanding. Could someone kindly do a step by step explanation of how to carry it out with at least one of the derivatives? Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay so by letting v = (( x sin^-1 (y)) we have that dv/dx = (( sin^-1 (y))             So this gives u = sin v to du/dv = cos (v) and hence du/dx = cos (x sin^-1 y )* (sin^-1 (y)) Is this on the right lines?

Comment: Well for $\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ using the chain rule you have

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\cos(x\sin^{-1}(y))\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x\sin^{-1}(y))=\cos(x\sin^{-1}(y))\cdot x\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

We are working with partial derivatives, so we treat one of the variables as a constant when we take the derivative with respect to the other, it is important not to forget the product and chain rule of course.

we have the $u=\sin((x\arcsin(y))$

The derivative with respect to x is ; $$\frac{\partial u}{ dx}=\cos(x\arcsin(y))(1)=\cos(x\arcsin(y))$$ for example

but $$\frac{\partial u}{dy}=\cos(x\arcsin(y))\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}2y$$